# How can I share folium map on the web?

Tags: python, web-mapping, jupyter-notebook, folium

I have created a folium map with markers and popups in jupyter notebook and saved it as `map.html`
I am looking for a way to share this map with others or host on the web, such that the markers and popups show. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answers [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/your-cool-folium-maps-on-the-web-313f9d1a6bcd), [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/data-visualization-deploying-an-interactive-map-as-a-web-app-with-heroku-51a323029e4) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379374/insert-the-folium-maps-into-the-jinja-template/60031784#60031784).